# How to manage different queue for each tenant in Multi-tenant SaaS application?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, multi-tenant, saas

We are running a **multi-tenant SaaS application for the reward program**.

Currently, we are **managing each tenant's queue separately in the database**.

Each tenant **can have a notification, reward, bulk_operations queues.**

Currently, we are managing **each queue in a single queue of that tenant**.

We know that **this is not the best approach** and best practice for doing it.

We are **planning to scale our application** in and we need to **set up queues and queue worker** **in the best possible way.**

Any suggestions would be great for that.
We are open to using any services for queue like SQS, Redis, etc.
We need a separate queue for each tenant.

**[Technicle details]**

Server:- AWS ec2

Language:- PHP

Framework:- Laravel 5.6

Database:- RDS Mysql

**[Requirements in terms of Throughput/Scalability]**

1. We have some tenant who has 100K jobs in a week or a day that might be increasing in the future as they are e-commerce store.
2. We have a daily minimum of 5-6 new tenants. So we need to manage their queues as well.
3. Each tenant's queue should be sperate so that one tenant doesn't need to depend on other tenant's process to be finished first. (Each tenant's process should be managed separately).

**[For more details on current structure]**

Please visit this question for a more detailed understanding of the current structure here -> [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150997/laravel-how-can-we-manage-different-queue-for-each-tenant-in-multi-tenant-applic)

Comment: What are your requirements in terms of throughput, scalability, etc.?

Comment: In that question, we just ask about Laravel database queue management.
@dparoli

Comment: @Namoshek I have updated questions with details as you asked. Please review it.

Comment: @dparoli Added (y).

Answer (score 0):

**Redis** works fine for starters. Easy to configure and install. 
You should also try **laravel horizon**. You can easily configure queues on horizon at config/horizon.php from there you can create separate notification, reward, bulk_operations connections you just need to specify it on your dispatch.

```
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->onQueue('processing');
```

you can check the official documentations of laravel horizon here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon

and for the queues and connections here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#customizing-the-queue-and-connection

Comment: 1. Can we create a new queue for a new tenant? 
2. Can we run the worker for each queue separately? 
3. Where do we need to manage worker for the queues? 
    Can we manage that in AWS lambda or we need to setup Different instance for that?

Comment: 1. yes you can but dynamically and using laravel horizon. please look at this. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-dynamically-generate-queues-in-laravel-horizon

Comment: 2. if you follow the link I share. it will run the worker separately without being dependent on other queues
3. you can manage your queues on horizon if you install it. follow the installation carefully and make sure to be carefull on your dashboard authentication so that it will not be open on your clients. or publicly.

honestly im not sure about lambda. i didn't use it as of now :)

Comment: also please read carefully the dashboard authentication when you install laravel horizon.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon#installation

Comment: Great Let me review it with my team.